# Submit checkboxes in JSP form submission to Spring controller

Tags: javascript, spring, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a 'to-do list' type web app using Spring and JSP. My `tasks.jsp` page displays a list of tasks from a database. Some JSON is passed to the view and used to create the HTML table, via a JS function in `tasks.js`. Resulting in below view:

[image]

I now want to be able to select tasks via checkboxes (seen to the right of each row) and delete those chosen rows. The tasks table is a form and the 'Delete Selected' button is used to submit the form.

I'm using a field from the tasks JSON (an ID) passed into the view as the value for each checkbox, so each one has a unique value associated with a particular row.

When I click 'Delete Selected' I can verify that a checkbox value is submitted to my controller as I print out that value in `taskDelete()`.

My problem is, only one value is ever printed even if I check multiple boxes. How can I get my form to submit a list of all the checkbox values which have been checked?

**TaskController.jsp**

```
package com.petehallw.todolist.main;

@Controller
public class TaskController {

    private static final String TASKS = "/tasks";
    private static final String DELETE_TASK = TASKS + "/delete";

    @Autowired
    private TaskEntityDao taskEntityDao;

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @RequestMapping(value = TASKS, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView readTasks() 
    {
        List<TaskEntity> tasks = taskEntityDao.readAllTasks();
        String tasksJson;

        try {
            tasksJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(tasks);
            return new ModelAndView("tasks", "tasksJson", tasksJson);
        } catch (IOException  e) {
            // ...
        }       
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = DELETE_TASK, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String taskDelete(@ModelAttribute("selectedTasks") String selectedTasks)
    {           
        System.out.println(selectedTasks);
        return "taskDeleted";
    }
}
```

**tasks.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri = "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix = "form"%>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/stylesheet.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/tasks.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>My Tasks</h2>
    <div>
        <form:form action = "tasks/delete">
            <table>
                <tbody id="tasks_table_body"/>
            </table>
            <div>
                <input type = "submit" value = "Delete Selected"/>
                <input type = "submit" value = "Do something else"/>
            </div>
        </form:form>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="actions">
        <a href="addTask">Add Task</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Populate tasks table. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        taskJsonToTable(${tasksJson});
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**tasks.js**

```
/**
 * Populate the tasks table from JSON.
 * @param tasksJson A JSON array representing the tasks data from the database.
 */
function taskJsonToTable(tasksJson)
{   
    var tableBody = document.getElementById('tasks_table_body');

    var tableHeaders = "<tr><th>Title</th>"
            + "<th>Description</th>"
            + "<th>Due Date</th>"
            + "<th>Priority</th>"
            + "<th>Select</th></tr>";

    /* Add the table headers to the table. */
    tableBody.innerHTML += tableHeaders;

    for (var i = 0; i < tasksJson.length; i++) 
    {       
        var tableContent = "<tr>";

        tableContent += "<td>" + tasksJson[i].title + "</td>" 
                + "<td>" + tasksJson[i].description + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + tasksJson[i].dueDate.toString() + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + tasksJson[i].priority + "</td>" 
                + "<td><input type='checkbox' name='selectedTasks' value='" +
                + tasksJson[i].taskId + "'"
                + "/></td></tr>";

        /* Add the table row to the table. */
        tableBody.innerHTML += tableContent;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use array String [] selectedTasks in the controller to get multiple checkboxes with the same name. And to access each one, use the index of them selectedTasks[0].

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt That doesn't seem to work - I still get one value returned. I tried `taskDelete(@ModelAttribute("selectedTasks") String[] selectedTasks)` and then checked the length of the array, which was still 1 with multiple boxes checked.

Comment: have you tried `taskDelete(@RequestParam String[] selectedTasks)` ?

Comment: @shantaram_t I had not tried that, but it works! I guess I am confused between `@ModelAttribute` and `@RequestParam`.. Many thanks - please post an answer so I can give you due credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**replace**

```
taskDelete(@ModelAttribute("selectedTasks") String[] selectedTasks)
```

**to**

```
taskDelete(@RequestParam String[] selectedTasks)
```